# I'm trying to make a user input dictionary for extra credit in my class and I can't figure out how to properly end the program

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, exit

```
my_dict = dict()
more = True
while more:
  bad_input = True

  while bad_input:
    user_input = input("Enter key and value seperated buy commas(,):")
    result = user_input.find(',') 
    print ("Substring ',' found at index:", result )

    if result != -1 and user_input != 'quit':
      bad_input = False
      key , value = user_input.split(",")
      key = key.strip()
      value = value.strip()
      my_dict[key] = value
      print (my_dict)
  if user_input == 'quit':
    print(my_dict)
    break
```

This is my code and I need it to find the ',' in the user input dictionary and also when you type 'quit' the program needs to end. My teacher is not educated in python enough to help me, please help!

Answer (score 0):

`break` only breaks the inner loop. In order to break out of the nested `while` loops without changing too much of your logic you will need to change the values that they check.

In this case, setting both `bad_input` and `more` to `False` will suffice:

```
if user_input == 'quit':
    print(my_dict)
    more = False
    bad_input = False
```

With that said, you don't even need both loops. Use a single `while` then you will be able to use `break`:

```
my_dict = dict()
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter key and value separated buy commas(,):")
    result = user_input.find(',')
    print("Substring ',' found at index:", result )

    if result != -1 and user_input != 'quit':
        bad_input = False
        key , value = user_input.split(",")
        key = key.strip()
        value = value.strip()
        my_dict[key] = value
        print (my_dict)
    if user_input == 'quit':
        print(my_dict)
        break
```